# Is it possible to define a group structure on arbitrary set?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, logic, cardinals, large-cardinals

Is it possible to define a group structure on arbitrary set? It is obvious for finite sets and also sets with cardinality |Q| and |R| and also we don't know that is there other cardinality betwen them or not... what can we say a bout sets with other cardinalities?